# How to check address of pointer variable in C

Tags: c

I was trying to print the address of the pointer variable not the address where it is pointing to, could anyone assist me in achieving that?
Below is what I am trying but it is showing warning which i am not able to resolve.
Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int* y;
    printf("%p\n",y);
    printf("%x\n",&y);
    y = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    printf("%p\n",y);
    printf("%x\n",&y);
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation warning:

```
Warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’,
    but argument 2 has type ‘int **’ 

Output:
0xb773fff4
bfa3594c
0x8361008
bfa3594c
```

Comment: You took its address with `&` correctly -- the printf hints are just hints

Comment: Both `y` and `&y` are pointer values. Why are you using `%p` to print one pointer value, but suddenly switch to `%x` for another pointer value? All of your `printf` statements are printing pointers, which means that all of them should use `%p`.

Comment: Also, I find it hard to believe that the output you posted was produced by the code you posted. You posted either wrong code, or wrong output.

Comment: @AndreyT Sorry, you got it right I have to edit the output, I was trying too much with %x and %p to print the address of the pointer variable itself, and somewhere in between posted the code in hurry I am correcting it. Appreciate your assistance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second `printf()` should take a `"%p\n"` format, and strictly a cast:

```
printf("%p\n", (void *)&y);
```

The number of machines where the cast actually changes anything is rather limited.

Comment: As a comment, `%x` is unsigned int, and for example on 64bit machines, this will not be same as `%p`.
As Jonathan said, always `%p` for pointers

Comment: I'm glad AndreyT asked you about the output because the original output didn't make much sense. Unfortunately, I was helping my kids with homework at the same time and didn't get to raise the question. Be aware that the format for `%p` varies between platforms. If you want to control the pointer format (I usually do), then use `<stdint.h>` and `printf("0x%.8" PRIXPTR "\n", (muintptr_t)&y);`. This uses string concatenation and the macros defined in the header to format the address with at least 8 digits and with upper-case hex digits and the `0x` prefix. Not all platforms add the `0x` prefix.

Answer (score -1):

The code seems to compile without warning or error on Visual Studio 2012.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
        int* y = 0;
        printf("%p\n",y);
        printf("%x",&y);
        y = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
        printf("%p\n", y);
        printf("%x",  &y);

        return 0;
    }
```

The only recommendation is that you initialize y when you declare it.

Comment: I think your answer is a sign that Visual Studio is broken, not that the code is fine. Perhaps you need to turn on more warnings - the warning is valid!